# Planning a school workshop on the Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, education

So I'm doing a mathematics education extension for my current undergraduate maths course, and for one bit of the final assessment we're asked to create a detailed lesson plan on the (strong) Goldbach Conjecture.

Part of the task is to make it a flexible enough plan that it's fairly independent of age and time allotted. We're also assuming the students know at least what primes are.

I've got a few ideas (listed below), but I was just wondering if there's any interesting/novel ways of explaining or exploring the Goldbach Conjecture at primary or secondary student level? There seems to be some interesting symmetry/geometric number line intuition one can draw, but I'm not sure how to make that concrete.

Here's what I got so far,

- Explain the conjecture, provide some simple examples to begin
- Visual worksheet to get a 'feel' for it, (eg. Filling in blanks in on a diagram similar to the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Goldbach_partitions_of_the_even_integers_from_4_to_50_rev4b.svg))
- (For secondary students, having not mentioned whether its proved or not), practice forming an induction argument. Why does it fail? (eg. [this post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155083/why-proof-by-induction-fails-for-goldbachs-conjecture))
- Talk a bit about the twin prime conjecture and how it's related
- (For any age) discuss the difference between showing the conjecture is true for many numbers, and a rigorous proof. (Eg. We know the pythagorean theorem is always true)

Are there any other interesting, mathematical concepts one can easily draw from the Goldbach conjecture?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that [tag:soft-question] is a tag

Comment: So that you know, there is also a [matheducators.stackexchange](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/). I suspect this may be more appropriate there.

Comment: Ah thanks @suomynonA , Yes I'll probably post there too, but I was kinda hoping there might be some particular mathematical offshoots from the Goldbach conjecture, which might otherwise not be immediately obvious?